# Button UA styles not resetting

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, button

I'm trying to make some CSS responsive shapes,
but while working with divs they react correctly,
with the `button` tag I can't reset UserAgent styles so the rendering is messed up;

here's a fiddle of what's happening http://jsfiddle.net/maio/hy1v45ej/2/

Comment: Here's a simpler demo of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hy1v45ej/3/

Comment: What user agent styles in particular are the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to clear necessary styles to render how you want it use this

```
button{ box-sizing: inherit; background-color: transparent;}
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hy1v45ej/4/

Comment: I had tried using `border-box:box-sizing` but chrome was computing  `border-box:content-box` do you know why? ...  with `box-sizing: inherit; ` it's now working